# BASH process grep output store in variable

Tags: bash, aix

I would like to get the following output and put into an array

```
grep password /etc/security/user
```

Output:

```
password = 123456
password = 412412
```

I would like to process this and get second portion of the output "123456" & "412412".
Preferably place them in an array.

My intent is to check if {sha256} or {sha512} is infront of the password.

Comment: Search for `command substitution`.  Read about arrays in the manual.

Comment: Saying `info bash` might help.

Comment: And don't forget to visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) you can use the code to assign passwords into an array:

```
$ eval $(sed -e 's/.* = //' -e = 1.cat | sed -e 'N;s/\([0-9]\+\)\n\(.*\)/array[\1]="\2"/')
$ echo ${array[1]}, ${array[2]}
123456, 412412
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
grep password /etc/security/user > input
```

I know three ways:

**1) cut command:**

```
cut -d= -f2 input | cut -c 2-
```

**2) awk command:**

```
awk < input -F= '{ print $2 }' | cut -c 2-
```

**3) sed command:

```
cat input | sed "s/.* = //"
```

Here `input` is your input file

Comment: Number of choices OP has is probably closer to 100 than 3. Also don't think there is a good reason to re-post another person's answer here.